# Defining actionless abilities in cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I wish to allow admins to create posts with custom fields, but still wish for them to use the same create action as normal users use.

I thought to do this:

```
class Ability
   include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
      if user.admin?
          can :specialize, Post
      end
   end
end
```

Then in my controller:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new
    if can? :specialize, @post
        do_fancy_things_here
    end
end
```

The weird thing is, do_fancy_things_here is ALWAYS running regardless of if the user is an admin or not.

This is strange. The only way I deviated from the cancan manuals is that :specialize does not actually map to a controller action. Does that matter?

Comment: I'm curious, if you change your if statement to: `if can? :specialize, Post`, do you still get the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have to use `authorize! :specialize, @post` in your controller.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-Controller-Actions